# Does introduction of stateless view to JSF disables implicit CSRF countermeasure `javax.faces.ViewState`?

Tags: jsf, csrf

My understandings are that JSF originally has implicit CSRF countermeasures, which is `javax.faces.ViewState`, to POST request.  If bad person infers or defaces `javax.faces.ViewState` value, JSF cannot restore the component tree and throws `ViewExpiredException`.

JSF 2.2 introduces stateless view.
And I noticed that if I modifies `javax.faces.ViewState`'s hidden value in HTML to `stateless`, JSF silently accept that value and functions as stateless mode.

Does this means that implicit tolerance of CSRF, which stems from `javax.faces.ViewState`, is lost in JSF 2.2?
Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: JSF 2.2 is an 'api' version... Mojarra/MyFaces are implementations and have concrete versions. What did you use? Tried the other? Tried latest versions? And did you actually encounter a security issue?

Comment: I'm sorry to be late.  We use MyFaces.  And I found the [issue I submitted here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MYFACES-3714), and that have been already fixed.

Comment: MyFaces version that we use may be old.  I'll check that.  
Thank you!